# hyperledger fabric set up on k8s fails to deploy containers

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I am using aws and kops to deploy kubernetes cluster and kubectl to manage it https://medium.com/@zhanghenry/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-2-751abf44c807 following this tutorial.
but when i try to deploy pods i get following error.

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "org1-pv" : mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/73568350-cfc0-11e8-ad99-0a84e5efbfb6/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/org1-pv --scope -- mount -t nfs nfs-server-IP:/opt/share/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/73568350-cfc0-11e8-ad99-0a84e5efbfb6/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/org1-pv Output: Running as unit run-24458.scope. mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

i have configured external nfs server such as

```
/opt/share      *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check following things to verify that nfs is mounted successfully or not

1. run this command on node where you want to mount.

   **`$showmount -e nfs-server-ip`**

like in my case **`$showmount -e 172.16.10.161`**
Export list for 172.16.10.161:
/opt/share *

2. use **`$df -hT`** command see that Is nfs is mounted or not like in my case it will give output  **`172.16.10.161:/opt/share nfs4       91G   32G   55G  37% /opt/share`**

if not mounted then use following command

```
$sudo mount -t nfs 172.16.10.161:/opt/share /opt/share
```

3. if above commands show error then check firewall is allowing nfs or not

   **`$sudo ufw status`**

   if not then allow using command

   **`$sudo ufw allow from nfs-server-ip to any port nf`s**

I made the same setup I don't faced any issues.[My cluster of fabric is running successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czGcO.png)

Comment: my ufw is inactive and nfs-server is mounted. what i've done is used an ec2 instance to create cluster of k8's and on same ec2 i'm generating artifacts and mounted my external nfs server on that ec2 on /opt/share. in templates i've provided ip of nfs server and when i run run.py pods status is container creating after some time i get above error. should i mount nfs server on master and node manually going into instance. can you help me figure out..?

Comment: i figured out my k8 nodes were not able to connect on internal ip of ec2 so i used public ip now it works good. can you please tell me how you are using storage class is it dynamically provisioned if yes how..? because on aws by default it takes ebs gp2 and if not found throws error so i have to create a storage class named nfs and assinged it in pv & pvc.

Comment: No I haven't use Storage Class. I have made this setup on local cloud in which there is kubernetes cluster and nfs server VM in which I have used LVM for creation of nfs storage like you can increase the storage dynamically ( but manually) and mount it on each nodes where pods are going to spawn.